# Signature Denied in PUT upload to S3 with Pre-Signed URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

Why might I be getting a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error from a S3 Amazon Pre-Signed Url PUT request?

I am using the AWS Javascript SDK to generate the signed `putObject` url and posting with a jQuery Ajax PUT request using Dropzone.js to manage file uploads.

Uploads work with `curl -v -T <IMAGE> <PRE-SIGNED-URL>`.

---

Request:

```
// Send uploads to s3 signed urls.
// @param res [Object] of signed-url's for image files.
function sendFiles(res){
  res.forEach(function(signedUrl){
    // Get file for associated Dropzone queued file.
    var file = returnFile(signedUrl.options.id);

    // signedUrl.url returns:
    // https://bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/(key:filename)Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1449874843&Signature=####&x-amz-acl=public-read-write`
    $.ajax({
      url: signedUrl.url,
      type: 'PUT',
      data: file.upload,
      contentType:'multipart/form',
      dataType: 'json',
      complete:function(data){
        console.log("Done", data);
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log("Error", data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Response:

```
<Code>
   SignatureDoesNotMatch
</Code>
<Message>
   The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.   
   Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

Comment: I had the issue until I realised that the pre-signed URL needs to be URLDecoded... (?)

Comment: @Julian Interesting, I am reading an [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2656-url-encoding-amazon-s3-resource-keys-for-pre-signed-urls-in-coldfusion.htm) now about your `URLDecodeFormat()` suggestion.  Indeed this is possible, I will try.

Comment: Feeling real good about your suggestion. RFC 3986 says the `-` char can't be escaped and I am using a uuid v4 signature as my key `9d8bd4d6-9293-4432-a3f5-fa7119c3d493` which is currently being sent as `9d8bd4d6%29293%24432%2a3f5%2fa7119c3d493`.

Comment: @Julian Unfortunately that didn't work. I stripped the `-` char from the uuid string and ran `decodeURIComponent(url)` on it since this is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution.**  This took two modifications.  I hope someone could explain them better.

---

*First*

I had to run `decodeURIComponent()` on the returned s3 signed url string from the aws-sdk.

*Second*

I had to change three and add two new options to the ajax PUT request.

```
{
  data: file,
  contentType:'image/jpeg',
  dataType:"text",
  cache : false,
  processData : false
}
```